# EF adding entity: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to add some newly created entities to my database, but EF is throwing an `InvalidOperationException` with the message `The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable` but it does not tell me which relationship is of issue.

Here are the relevant entities:

DatabaseContext OnModelCreating:

```
...

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Home)
    .WithMany(s => s.StudentsInResidence)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.HomeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<SignoutRequest>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Destination)
    .WithMany(x => x.RequestsToHere)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DestinationId);

modelBuilder.Entity<SignoutRequest>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Subject)
    .WithMany(x => x.SignoutRequests)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.SubjectId);

...
```

SignoutRequest:

```
public class SignoutRequest
{
    public SignoutRequest()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectId { get; set; }
    ... 
    public int? DestinationId { get; set; }

    #region Custom Fields
    ...
    #endregion

    #region Virtual Properties
    ...
    public virtual Student Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceGroup Destination { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```

Student:

```
public class Student : IWpEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int Form { get; set; }
    public int HomeId { get; set; }

    public virtual DeviceGroup Home { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BlacklistEntry> BlacklistEntries { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<SignoutRequest> SignoutRequests { get; set; }
}
```

DeviceGroup:

```
public class DeviceGroup : IWpEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> StudentsInResidence { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SignoutRequest> RequestsToHere { get; set; } 
}
```

IWpEntity is just a collection of methods.

And here is the code that throws the error:

```
_database.SubmittedRequests.Add(srq);
await _database.SaveChangesAsync();
```

`srq` is the `SignoutRequest` that I am trying to add to the database. It already has properties `SubjectId` and `DestinationId` set to valid IDs of objects already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea why, but I got rid of IWpEntity and it started working. I'm totally confused, and I have no idea why that would have any bearing on the Database. The design of the database in Sql Management Studio looks identical.